# how to resolve this type of error when inserting a new row in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE hypothesis AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Hypoth_pr AS OBJECT (prob_content VARCHAR2(20), pr NUMBER);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Hypoth_po AS OBJECT (possib_content VARCHAR2(20), po NUMBER);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE focal_element AS OBJECT(focal_element_content hypothesis, focal_element_mass NUMBER);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE bba AS TABLE OF focal_element;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Pr_Dist AS TABLE OF Hypoth_pr;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE po_Dist AS TABLE OF Hypoth_po;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE confidence_level AS OBJECT(bel NUMBER, pl NUMBER);
/
CREATE TABLE edb (pid VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY, Disease bba, Symptom Pr_Dist, Age po_Dist, cl CONFIDENCE_LEVEL)
NESTED TABLE Disease STORE AS Diseases (NESTED TABLE focal_element_content STORE AS focal_element_contents_fs),
NESTED TABLE Symptom STORE AS Symptoms
NESTED TABLE Age STORE AS Ages;
/
INSERT INTO edb VALUES ('2', bba(focal_element(hypothesis('Pneumonia',0.2)), focal_element(hypothesis('Cold','Fever'),0.6)),
pr_Dist(Hypoth_pr('Cough',0.5), Hypoth_pr('Headcaches',0.5)),
po_Dist(Hypoth_po('Old',1), Hypoth_po('Teenager',0.7)), 
CONFIDENCE_LEVEL(0.4,0.8));
```

> Erreur à la ligne de commande: 26 Colonne: 34
>   Rapport d'erreur -
>   Erreur SQL : ORA-02315: nombre d'arguments non valide pour constructeur par défaut
>   02315. 00000 -  "incorrect number of arguments for default constructor"
>   *Cause:    The number of arguments specified for the default constructor
>              doesn't match the number of attributes of the object type.
>   *Action:   Specify the correct number of arguments for the default
>              constructor and retry the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted to use double `focal_element` for `bba`, but using redundant closing parentheses for the first one corrupts the syntax as `focal_element(hypothesis('Pneumonia')   ,0.2))
                                                                        -->^`

Try Insert statement below :

```
INSERT INTO edb VALUES ('2', 
bba(focal_element(hypothesis('Pneumonia')   ,0.2), 
    focal_element(hypothesis('Cold','Fever'),0.6) ),
pr_Dist(Hypoth_pr('Cough',0.5), Hypoth_pr('Headcaches',0.5)),
po_Dist(Hypoth_po('Old',1), Hypoth_po('Teenager',0.7)), 
CONFIDENCE_LEVEL(0.4,0.8));
```

Comment: he showed me this error:  'Erreur commençant à la ligne: 31 de la commande -
INSERT INTO edb VALUES ('2', 
bba(focal_element(hypothesis('Pneumonia')   ,0.2), 
    focal_element(hypothesis('Cold','Fever'),0.6) ),
pr_Dist(Hypoth_pr('Cough',0.5), Hypoth_pr('Headcaches',0.5)),
po_Dist(Hypoth_po('Old',1), Hypoth_po('Teenager',0.7)), 
CONFIDENCE_LEVEL(0.4,0.8))
Rapport d'erreur -
ORA-00001: violation de contrainte unique (SYSTEM.SYS_C0011499) '

Comment: @DORRAAMRI notice that the error message changed, and that suggests obviously the insert operation is violating the unique constraint on `pid` column. E.g. your issue is resolved. Just convert '2' to a diferent value which not yet been inserted into `edb`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved. But, but when I apply the query "select * from edb;" it shows me like that, instead of showing me a table.

Comment: you're welcome @DORRAAMRI . I didn't understand the part after "but" ...

Comment: PID
----------
DISEASE
SYMPTOM(PROB_CONTENT, PR)
AGE(POSSIB_CONTENT, PO)




PID
----------
DISEASE
SYMPTOM(PROB_CONTENT, PR)
AGE(POSSIB_CONTENT, PO)


2          
BBA(FOCAL_ELEMENT(HYPOTHESIS('Pneumonia'), 0,2), FOCAL_ELEMENT(HYPOTHESIS('Cold', 


PID
----------
DISEASE
SYMPTOM(PROB_CONTENT, PR)
AGE(POSSIB_CONTENT, PO)

Comment: you should be seeing `disease`, `symptom` and `age` fields as `collection`, and `pid` = 2, `cl.bel`=0,4, `cl.pl`=0,8 @DORRAAMRI

Comment: you can use treat function to query object type such as `select pid, treat(cl AS confidence_level).bel from edb`